# Can not edit date form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

im very new at laravel, and now, I'm building an edit form and the date of Birth will always back to time "1-1-1970" everytime i want to change it.

Whats wrong with my code?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date_of_bday">
        Date Of Birthday
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input id="single_cal1" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left @if($errors->has('date_of_bday')) parsley-error @endif"
                           name="date_of_bday" placeholder="Date Of Birthday" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status" value="{{ date('m/d/Y', strtotime($member->dob)) }}" required>
         <span class="fa fa-calendar form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check database? which date it is storing ?

Comment: check the date format on your database and the format of the date that you tried to store.

Comment: how can i check the date format? or where i can find the code to reformat it? im sorry if it's a silly question, newbie here.. hehe

Comment: could you do `value="{{ dd($member->dob) }}` and post the value of `$member->dob`

Comment: i got it, my format is different with the format that i tried ti store in my database, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) to parse the date and format it accordingly

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date_of_bday">
        Date Of Birthday
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input id="single_cal1" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left 
         @if($errors->has('date_of_bday')) parsley-error @endif" 
         name="date_of_bday" 
         placeholder="Date Of Birthday" 
         aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status" 
         value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($member->dob)->format('m/d/Y') }}" 
         required>
         <span class="fa fa-calendar form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```